# How do I monitor GCP node IP address

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

Mu virtual machines on GCP have ip address that change? How do I monitor and kick off an HTTP request when the ip address changes?

Comment: Do you mean the external public IP address? If yes, note that that IP address is not connected to your GCP VM. The VM is not aware of any changes. That means that you will need to write a program that runs periodically that checks for a change. Solution: use a static IP address.

Comment: To add to John's excellent answer ... see the following for reserving a static external IP address - https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address  If you reserve an IP, that IP is yours until you explicitly release it.  There is no charge if the IP is being used (eg. has a running compute engine).  If you are not using the IP, you are charged $0.01 per hour unused.

Answer (score 1):

You can reserve an [external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address) address following the steps from the documentation. You may check the costs of a [static IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/network-pricing#ipaddress) also you can calculate the costs of your instance using the [calculator](https://cloud.google.com/products/calculator/). Furthermore, if in the future you want to use a non-static IP address you can release this static IP anytime.